# How to implement outline view (like NSOutlineView) for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsoutlineview

There is `NSOutlineView` for macOS but UIOutlineView does not exist for iOS. What is the equivalent? How to implement outline view in iPhone apps?

Comment: Show image for what you want.

Comment: NSOutlineView sounds like expand-collapse tableview.  check it out -> https://github.com/canicelebrate/AECollapsableTableView